# python reverse iterator vs. generator behavior

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, generator, reverse

Why does removing items a list break `reversed`  objects? It doesn't break gen-exprs, and appending to or modifying  the list doesn't break the `reversed` object, and it obviously points to the original object, so why can't it give a truncated version? Perhaps some examples can clarify:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
r = reversed(l)
g = (i for i in l)
l.pop()  # returns 4
l   # returns [1, 2, 3]

for i in g:print(i)  # prints 1 2 3 (on separate lines)
for i in r:print(i)  # prints ...nothing

r = reverse(l)
g = (i for i in l)
l[1] = 4
for i in g:print(i)  # prints 1 4 3 (on separate lines)
for i in r:print(i)  # prints 3 4 1 (on separate lines)

r = reversed(l)
g = (i for i in l)
l.append(5)
l  # returns [1, 4, 3, 5] just to keep you on your toes

for i in g:print(i)  # prints 1 4 3 5 (on separate lines)
for i in r:print(i)  # prints 3 4 1   (on separate lines)
```

So - if the genexpr is smart enough to point to the object, and just respond to however the object has changed, why doesn't `reversed`? It obviously doesn't make a copy, otherwise it wouldn't "fail" on the first situation, and it wouldn't pick up the `4` in the second. So it must point to the object. Why can't it just start from index `-1` and work backwards?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the behavior of Python iterators (including `reversed` iterators) is unspecified when you modify the contents of the iterable while the iterator is running, so you should not be surprised by varying results. Some iterators may stop with an error (dictionary iterators do), while others may quit early (like the list reverse iterator your question is about), or skip or repeat elements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call `reversed()` on a list object, a dedicated reverse list iterator object is created; this object 'knows' how to efficiently iterate over the list in reverse order *once*.

To do this, when the object is created the *last index* in the list is stored. For your list `l`, that is `3` (the 4th element, counting from 0). When you then iterate, the element at that index is yielded, and the index is decremented, until an `IndexError` is raised <sup>*</sup>.

A Python implementation of the object would look like this:

```
class reversed_list_iterator(object):
    def __init__(self, lst):
        self.index = len(lst) - 1
        self.lst = lst

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        try:
            result = self.lst[self.index]
        except IndexError:
            self.lst = []  # switch to permanently stopped state
            raise StopIteration
        self.index -= 1
        return result
```

Now, when you then *remove* that element, the iterator exits as there is no `l[3]`, an `IndexError` is raised *there and then* and iteration ends.

In your second example, when creating the reversed iterator, the last index is `2`. You then *add* to the list, but iteration starts at `l[2]`, which still exists.

The reversed list iterator cannot use relative indices, because as you discovered, the iterator is relatively tolerant of elements being added to the list. A relative index would then repeat values.

---

<sup>*</sup> The [actual C implementation](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/267422f7c927/Objects/listobject.c#l2911) tests for the boundaries `0 <= index < len(self.lst)` rather than catch `IndexError`, but the principle is the same.

Comment: I guess my question would be: is there a loss in efficiency if instead of hard-coding that `len(l)`, it was replaced with a hardcoded `-1`?

Comment: @dwanderson: the behaviour would change, as now appending to the list would alter where the iterator would move to next. Add 5 elements and you set the iterator back by that much.

Comment: Hmm, ok, definitely true. I could see that being expected behavior though. But I guess if it's had this history of *not* doing that, that could break things.

Comment: Oh, interesting sidenote about the C implementation, thanks for the digging :). Looking at it though, `line 2918` looks as if it calls for the size of `seq` during the call to `next`, which  ... oh, okay: it starts out with `it_index` being the original `seq` length, then I shorten the list, so that `if` fails, and it thinks it's empty. That makes sense, at least why I see the behavior I do.

Comment: @dwanderson: it detects the index is out of bounds (would raise an `IndexError` if used in Python code).